# I get a traceback error when using the command "pipenv run python"

Tags: python, shell, pipenv, traceback

UPDATE: The issue comes from the special characters in the path where the .virtualenv directory is created.  I fixed it by rerouting the .virtualenv in C:  and will eventually edit the username to avoid this issue in the future.

I am having some trouble with "pipenv run" on my work laptop (windows pro) and can't seem to find an explanation to my issue.  For example, I create a test directory on the desktop in which I put a basic scripts that prints "Hello".

I initiate pipenv in the project folder and it works fine, I can fire up the shell, install packages, run the script (While in the shell), etc..

However, I get a traceback whenever I try to run the script from the main command prompt as such (not inside of pipenv shell):

```
C:\Users\jérôme\Desktop\tester> pipenv run python testit.py
```

some other details:

- running the above command on my personal machine (windows family edition) works fine
- I did "pipenv lock" before to check if it could be the issue.  It was not
- I am using python 3.7.9 on both machine
- Python was added to path variables on installation
- I tried with python 3.8.6 as well and get the same error
- I tried uninstalling completely all python versions and reinstalling it
- the username on my work machine as special characters (é, ô) could it be the reason?

Traceback Error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jérôme\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)

  File "c:\users\jérôme\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)

  File "C:\Users\jérôme\Python37\Scripts\pipenv.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>

  File "c:\users\jérôme\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)

  File "c:\users\jérôme\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)

  File "c:\users\jérôme\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))

  File "c:\users\jérôme\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)

  File "c:\users\jérôme\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)

  File "c:\users\jérôme\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)

  File "c:\users\jérôme\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)

  File "c:\users\jérôme\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 450, in run
    command=command, args=args, three=state.three, python=state.python, pypi_mirror=state.pypi_mirror

  File "c:\users\jérôme\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 2547, in do_run
    run_fn(*run_args, **run_kwargs)

  File "c:\users\jérôme\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 2468, in do_run_nt
    p = _launch_windows_subprocess(script)

  File "c:\users\jérôme\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 2458, in _launch_windows_subprocess
    return subprocess.Popen([command] + script.args, **options)

  File "c:\users\jérôme\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "c:\users\jérôme\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: To rule out the special characters you could create c:\tmp and test pipenv the same way in this tmp directory.

Comment: I am a bit ashamed I didn't try that before asking here.  Turns out the special characters in the path is the issue.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the problem are the special characters in the user's directory path, where the pipenv's .virtualenv directory is also created by default. The OP reports to have fixed the problem by rerouting the .virtualenv in C:

A quick test in, e.g. `c:\tmp` can help to rule out this cause.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, I solved it by uninstalling anaconda.